# Foreach in a query linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method on my Domain.Services project

```
    public IList GetGroupProduct(IPrincipal user, int year)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("user");
        }

        var query = (from p in _repository.GetRevenues()
            join o in _repository.GetEquipments() on p.IdEquipment.Equipment_Id equals
                o.Equipment_Id
            join c in _repository.GetGroupEquipment() on o.IdGroup.Group_Id equals
                c.Group_Id
            where p.DateTimeCreationData.Year == year
            orderby p.DateTimeCreationData
            select new
            {
                p.Quantity,
                p.Value,
                c.NameGroup
            }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

In my View I call

```
var listGroupProductsActualYear = receitaServico.GetGroupProduct(User, DateTime.Now.Year);
```

That works fine, but it's too difficult going through the results. I don't know if the best approach should return an IList or other type.

[image]

How can I do a `foreach` in this variable that has the return of my GetGrupoProduto method ?

Or how can I make a better approach, maybe not using IList.

**Another Method where I return a typed**

```
    public IEnumerable<Revenue.Revenue> GetRevenues(IPrincipal user, int year)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("user");
        }

        return from p in _repository.GetRevenues()
               where p.DateTimeCreationData.Year == year
               orderby p.DateTimeCreationData
               select p;
    }
```

Comment: the easy way is: don't use an anonymous type, use a named typed and return `IList<Yourtype>` from your method

Comment: Reading your code is harder than it has to be. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes).

Comment: @Selman22 I did it in another method, where I return the specific domain, but in this new case I did 2 join. I need do a new Domain just for this ?

Comment: @nvoigt I did the corrections to english

Comment: What do you mean by "Domain"? You don't need an extra edmx, just a regular class. And then, instead of `select new {..}` you do a `select new Yourtype() {..} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` feature

```
foreach(dynamic item in listaGruposProdutosAnoAtual)
{
    var quantity = item.Quantidade;
}
```

But I would higly recommend you to use a named type instead of *anonymous type* because this way is not *type-safe*.

Comment: But in this case, to do a named type, I need create another domain just fot this case ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos It'll take you all of 10 seconds to create a new class to hold this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a non-generic collection type or interface (and in most cases, you don't want to), you will have to create a new type to use as your return type (or use dynamics, but it's nearly just as bad).

```
public class MyReturnType
{
    public AType a {get; set;}
    public BType b {get; set;}
    public CType c {get; set;}
}

public IList<MyReturnType> GetGroupProduct(IPrincipal user, int year)
{
    ...
    select new MyReturnType
    {
        a=...,
        b=...,
        c=...
    }).ToList(); 
}
```